# Select previous and next word in a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm looping through a lot of strings like this one in C# :

> *“Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else.”*

In these strings, I have a single selected word, determined by an index from a previous function, like the second "good" in the case above.

> *“Look, good **(<- not this one)** against remotes is one thing, **good (<- this one)** against the living, that’s something else.”*

I want to find the words surrounding my selected word. In the case above, **thing** and **against**.

> *“Look, good against remotes is one **thing**, good **against** the living, that’s something else.”*

I have tried taking the string apart with `.split()` and different approaches with regular expressions, but I can't find a good way to achieve this. I have access to the word, **good** in the example above, and the index (41 above) where it's located in the string.

A huge bonus if it would ignore punctuation and commas, so that in the example above, my theoretical function would only return **against** since there is a comma between **thing** and **good**.

Is there a simple way to achieve this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'd probably just split on spaces and iterate manually, keeping track of the previous and next words. For punctuation, you may as well just have a list of characters that invalidate a word. You might be able to write it as an extension method that keeps track of three indices and uses some kind of count.

Comment: I have tried splitting on spaces and iterate, but I'm not sure how to not get stuck on the first **good** in the string and move on to the second one.

Comment: You iterate a counter when you find a match, and if the counter matches the position you pass in, you return.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Including the "huge bonus":

```
string text = "Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else.";
string word = "good";
int index = 41;

string before = Regex.Match(text.Substring(0, index), @"(\w*)\s*$").Groups[1].Value;
string after = Regex.Match(text.Substring(index + word.Length), @"^\s*(\w*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

In this case `before` will be an empty string because of the comma, and `after` will be "against".

Explanation: When getting `before`, the first step is to grab just the first part of the string up until just before the target word, `text.Substring(0, index)` does this.  Then we use the regular expression `(\w*)\s*$` to match and capture a word (`\w*`) followed by any amount of whitespace `\s*` at the end of the string (`$`).  The contents of the first capture group is the word we want, if we could not match a word the regex will still match but it will match an empty string or only whitespace, and the first capture group will contain an empty string.

The logic for getting `after` is pretty much the same, except that `text.Substring(index + word.Length)` is used to get the rest of the string after the target word.  The regex `^\s*(\w*)` is similar except that it is anchored to the beginning of the string with `^` and the `\s*` comes before the `\w*` since we need to strip off whitespace on the front end of the word.

Comment: This one actually seem to achieve the magic I am looking for. Amazing!

Comment: It seems that `before` will have a space in the end if there is no comma (e.g. `thing good against`) because `text.Substring(0, index)` ends with a space. Also, double spaces can be a problem.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze There will never be spaces as a part of `before` or `after`, since these are both coming from the `\w*` portion of the regex which can only match word characters.  Although this does bring up a good point about what a "word character" is, `\w` will match letters, numbers and underscore.  If you only want to match letters you could use `[a-zA-Z]` in place of `\w`.

Comment: @F.J What about `\s*` that will match ending white spaces? Tested here http://regexpal.com/

Comment: I have a follow-up that immediately followed this one, which I'm not sure if I'm should post another question about or not, but since it's closely related to this one. The words I'm getting out of before and after, is there any way to identify those? If I want to add a CSS-class to the after-word, and the after-word is "the", then my CSS will be applied to a whole lot of words. (Even worse with "a" and "I". Maybe suited for another question? :)

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze The `\s*` will match the white spaces, but the contents of the capture group are what we use for `before` and `after` and the capture group will never contain white spaces.

Comment: @MagnusEngdal Sounds like you should create another question, not closely related enough to the current one for an edit.

Comment: @F.J Makes sense, thanks for the explanation. Regex is for smart people;)

Comment: To resolve the follow-up above in a quick way, could you help me with the `Match` above, but replace it with `Replace`? Instead of actually getting the word before and after, I would just like to enclose them in `<span>before</span>word<span>after</span>`. I tried with something like this, but it didn't return what I expected: `string test = Regex.Replace(text.Substring(0, index), @"(\w*)\s*$", x => "<span>" + x.Groups[1] + "</span>");`

Answer (score 3):

```
string phrase = "Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else.";
int selectedPosition = 41;
char[] ignoredSpecialChars = new char[2] { ',', '.' };

string afterWord = phrase.Substring(selectedPosition)
                         .Split(' ')[1]
                         .Trim(ignoredSpecialChars);
string beforeWord = phrase.Substring(0, selectedPosition)
                          .Split(' ')
                          .Last()
                          .Trim(ignoredSpecialChars);
```

You can change `ignoredSpecialChars` array to get rid of the special characters you don't need.

**UPDATE:**

This will return `null` if there are any special characters between your word and words that surround it.

```
string phrase = "Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else.";
int selectedPosition = 41;
char[] ignoredSpecialChars = new char[2] { ',', '.' };

string afterWord = phrase.Substring(selectedPosition)
                         .Split(' ')[1];
afterWord = Char.IsLetterOrDigit(afterWord.First()) ?
            afterWord.TrimEnd(ignoredSpecialChars) : 
            null;

string beforeWord = phrase.Substring(0, selectedPosition)
                          .Split(' ')
                          .Last();
beforeWord = Char.IsLetterOrDigit(beforeWord.Last()) ?
             beforeWord.TrimStart(ignoredSpecialChars) : 
             null;
```

Comment: The question is "How do I get the words before and after the Nth occurrence of <word>, unless separated by punctuation."

Comment: Well this one helped a lot, even though the "huge bonus" wasn't fulfilled. Accepting this one for now, since it solves my main problem. Thanks Nikolai!

Comment: @AlexBeisley `I want to find the words surrounding my selected word. In the case above, thing and against.` Am I missing something?

Comment: @MagnusEngdal So, in your example, do you need `thing` or not?

Comment: The selected word is what you're missing. He wants the words surrounding the second occurrence of a word in a string, most likely without requiring a human to look at the string and count the characters.

Comment: @AlexBeisley `I have access to the word, good in the example above, and the index (41 above) where it's located in the string.`

Comment: In this case: "thing, good against", I would prefer to just get against, but in this case "thing good against" I would like both thing and against. Ignore words separated by punctuation or comma.

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze: Ah, he must've fixed his iteration then. Before that wasn't the case, he was getting stuck on the first occurrence.

Comment: @MagnusEngdal Updated my answer. Was a little confused by `A huge bonus if it would ignore punctuation and commas'. I thought you want to ignore special characters.

Comment: Huge upvote for you, but F.Js answer really did the trick for me. Amazing how many good solutions there where to this problem. Thank you Nikolai!

Answer (score 0):

i haven't tested it yet, but it should work. You can just look at the Substring before and after the word and then search for the first or the last " ". Then you know where the words start and end.

```
string word = "good";
int index = 41

string before = word.Substring(0,index-1).Trim();   //-1 because you want to ignore the " " right in front of the word
string after = word.Substring(index+word.length+1).Trim();   //+1 because of the " " after the word

int indexBefore = before.LastIndexOf(" ");
int indexAfter = after.IndexOf(" ");

string wordBefore = before.Substring(indexBefore, index-1);
string wordAfter = after.Substring(index+word.length+1, indexAfter);
```

**EDIT**

and if you want to ignore punctuation and commas, just remove them from your string

Comment: Minor flaw: breaks if there are double spaces in the string. `indexBefore` will be incorrect. You can use `Trim()` on `before` string to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression `[^’a-zA-Z]+` to get words from your string:

```
words = Regex.Split(text, @"[^’a-zA-Z0-9]+");
```

Implementing navigation is up to you. Store index of selected word and use it to get next one or previous:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(words, "living");
if (index < words.Count() - 1)
    next = words[index + 1]; // that's

if (index > 0)
    previous = words[index - 1]; // the
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a linqpad program written in vb

```
    Sub Main
    dim input as string = "Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else."

    dim words as new list(of string)(input.split(" "c))

    dim index = getIndex(words)

    dim retVal = GetSurrounding(words, index, "good", 2)

    retVal.dump()
End Sub

function getIndex(words as list(of string)) as dictionary(of string, list(of integer))

    for i as integer = 0 to words.count- 1
            words(i) = getWord(words(i))
    next

    'words.dump()

    dim index as new dictionary(of string, List(of integer))(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    for j as integer = 0 to words.count- 1
            dim word = words(j)
            if index.containsKey(word) then
                    index(word).add(j)
            else  
                    index.add(word, new list(of integer)({j}))
            end if
    next

    'index.dump()
    return index
end function

function getWord(candidate) as string
    dim pattern as string = "^[\w'’]+"
    dim match = Regex.Match(candidate, pattern)
    if match.success then
            return match.toString()
    else
            return candidate
    end if
end function 

function GetSurrounding(words, index, word, position) as tuple(of string, string)        

    if not index.containsKey(word) then
            return nothing
    end if

    dim indexEntry = index(word)
    if position > indexEntry.count
            'not enough appearences of word
            return nothing
    else
            dim left = ""
            dim right = ""
            dim positionInWordList = indexEntry(position -1)
            if PositionInWordList >0
                    left = words(PositionInWordList-1)
            end if
            if PositionInWordList < words.count -1
                    right = words(PositionInWordList +1)
            end if

            return new tuple(of string, string)(left, right)
    end if
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the regex this can be done recursively with `Array.IndexOf`.

```
public class BeforeAndAfterWordFinder
{
    public string Input { get; private set; }
    private string[] words;

    public BeforeAndAfterWordFinder(string input)
    {
        Input = input;
        words = Input.Split(new string[] { ", ", " " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
    }

    public void Run(int occurance, string word)
    {
        int index = 0;
        OccuranceAfterWord(occurance, word, ref index);
        Print(index);            
    }

    private void OccuranceAfterWord(int occurance, string word, ref int lastIndex, int thisOccurance = 0)
    {
        lastIndex = lastIndex > 0 ? Array.IndexOf(words, word, lastIndex + 1) : Array.IndexOf(words, word);

        if (lastIndex != -1)
        {
            thisOccurance++; 
            if (thisOccurance < occurance)
            {
                OccuranceAfterWord(occurance, word, ref lastIndex, thisOccurance);
            }                
        }            
    }

    private void Print(int index)
    {            
        Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", words[index - 1], words[index + 1]);//check for index out of range
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
  string input = "Look, good against remotes is one thing, good against the living, that’s something else.";
  var F = new BeforeAndAfterWordFinder(input);
  F.Run(2, "good");
```

Answer (score -2):

create a string where you remove punctuation and commas (use Remove). from that string, search  for Substring "thing good against".
and so on, if needed.

Comment: This is the opposite of what the question is asking for.

Comment: You're asking him to pass in an incorrect version of the results he wants in order to get something he didn't ask for.

Comment: no I´m not. he wanted a version without punctuation and commas, which I provide a valid solution for. are you having a bad day or something? don´t take it out on me.

Comment: He asked to find the word before and after a word, unless separated by punctuation. Try again.

Comment: maybe you missed this part of his question: "A huge bonus if it would ignore punctuation and commas"?